# How to enable LDAP in XAMPP?

Tags: ldap, xampp

I am trying to enable LDAP in XAMPP 1.8.1 on Ubuntu 12.10. Can any one help me out, how to do it?

When I did bit of googling, most of links were talking about Windows operating system. No where I found LDAP in XAMPP on Ubuntu.

Comment: Why not setup your own [LAMP stack](http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat/) instead of relying on XAMPP? Is there any particular reason you need LDAP juxtaposed with XAMPP?

Comment: Agree with djthoms. Using LDAP I assume this is a business related setup? Please use the LAMP(P) stack. It is set up for Ubuntu, it is far more secure and even the guys that made XAMPP agree that it should -not- be used in an environment where others can reach your website.

Comment: We are trying to implement SSO for a few products. The aim is to get these products working across multiple platforms. LAMP works. But we are unable to get LDAP working with Xampp even though it is enabled. Any help with the integration would be greatly appreciated.